# Sizing issue on screen sizes less than 475px in Tailwind CSS

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, screen-size

[Reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXCm7.png)

I am building a dummy website with shapes, but there are some issues with screen sizing.

You can see in the above image that there are some sizing issues with the website when using Chrome DevTools to view how the website would look in different screen sizes.

[Source code](https://github.com/turbofuture1/shapo)

I am using the latest version of Tailwind and Next.js, but I still get this annoying whitespace.

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `initial-scale` and device width properties with your `<Head>` element to fix the issue - without the `initial-scale`, the browser does not do its bit to fill in contents to available viewport width's.

`pages/index.js`

`<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />`

A Detailed explanation of how device width and initial scale work and what viewports actually do with different devices can be reviewed here at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag)

Comment: Thanks! It works, but with screen sizes less than 300px, the same thing happens again. Any way to fix this?

Comment: No devices I know have screen size less than 300 px